# Groovy throws MissingPropertyException when calling getter method

Tags: groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm writing a small Groovy script for Hybris.

For reasons unknown when I attempt to call .getCronExpression() Groovy tries to get a property named getCron.

```
Script execution has failed [reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: getCron for class: de.hybris.platform.cronjob.model.TriggerModel]
```

The getter which I try to call exists on the class.

```
def methods = TriggerModel.declaredMethods.findAll { !it.synthetic }.name
println methods;
//[getDaysOfWeek, getWeekInterval, setDaysOfWeek, setWeekInterval, getRelative, getJob, setActivationTime, setMaxAcceptableDelay, getTimeTable, setActive, setJob, getCronJob, getActivationTime, setDateRange, getDateRange, getMaxAcceptableDelay, getCronExpression, setCronExpression, setCronJob, getActive, setRelative, setDay, setHour, setMinute, setSecond, getHour, getMinute, getSecond, getYear, getMonth, setYear, setMonth, getDay]
```

Code part:

```
def currentDate = new Date();
def query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {pk} FROM {cronjob} WHERE {active} IS true");
def result = flexibleSearchService.search(query).getResult();
for (cj in result) {
  def activeTriggers = cj.getTriggers().stream().filter{p -> p.getActive()}.collect();

  if (activeTriggers){
    def at = activeTriggers.get(0);
    def activationTS = at.getActivationTime(); // works
    if (activationTS.before(currentDate)){
      println cj.code + " has invalid next activation date set: " + activationTS; 
    }

    def x = at.getCronExpression(); // error
  }
```

Update: the project uses hybris 5.7

Comment: Indeed, I tried our code and i got the same error, but seems `at._cronExpression;` is working as a workaround (the groovy seems to be skipping "Expression" word)

Comment: How is that possible? Expression is not a reserved keyword in Groovy.  It could be related to the hybris version we are using (5.7).

Comment: I think so, seems this  was fixed on the latest versions of hybris

Comment: On Hybris 2011 I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the *getter* with the *variable name* fixed the issue.

Replace-

```
def x = at.getCronExpression(); // error
```

with

```
def xam = at.cronExpression; // working
```

Complete working groovy-

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;

def currentDate = new Date();
def query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {pk} FROM {cronjob} WHERE {active}='1'");
def result = flexibleSearchService.search(query).getResult();
for (cj in result) {
  def activeTriggers = cj.getTriggers().stream().filter{p -> p.getActive()}.collect();

  if (activeTriggers){
    def at = activeTriggers.get(0);
    def activationTS = at.getActivationTime(); // works
    if (activationTS.before(currentDate)){
      println cj.code + " has invalid next activation date set: " + activationTS; 
    }

    def xam = at.cronExpression; // working
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it. But does not answer why Groovy is not able to call the getter properly.

Comment: Having the same issue "No such property: setCron" when using setCronExpression(). Same for get. Hybris 2011. I bet that it is related to upgrading Groovy in Hybris. In Groovy 2.5 there were some major changes like e.g. groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(). Maybe there were also issues with former Groovy updates in Hybris.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your groovy part where you are loading `activeTriggers`?

I created a sample groovy to load Triggers and print `CronExpression` for 1st object and it worked like a charm.

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;

flexibleQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("select {pk} from {Trigger}");
flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")
activeTriggers = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleQuery).getResult();

def at = activeTriggers.get(0);
def x = at.getCronExpression();
```

OUTPUT

```
0 0 0/4 * * ? *
```

**AFTER PO EDITED THE QUESTION** I still don't see `getCronExpression` error, I believe you were calling the function on a different object then `TriggerModel`. Though there were some syntax errors in your groovy, a working version of the copy is as below. *(Tested on 1905 version)*

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;

def currentDate = new Date();
def query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {pk} FROM {cronjob} WHERE {active} = true");
def result = flexibleSearchService.search(query).getResult();
for (cj in result) {
  def activeTriggers = cj.getTriggers().stream().filter{p -> p.getActive()}.collect();

  if (activeTriggers){
    def at = activeTriggers.get(0);
    def activationTS = at.getActivationTime(); // works
    if (activationTS!=null && activationTS.before(currentDate)){
      println cj.code + " has invalid next activation date set: " + activationTS; 
    }

    def x = at.getCronExpression(); // error
    println x;
  }

}
```

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: What error are you getting now? It seems you must not be getting the problem you were facing earlier i.e., _cronExpression not found

Comment: @www.hybriscx.com what version of hybris you are using?

Comment: Having the same issue "No such property: setCron" when using setCronExpression(). Same for get. Hybris 2011. I bet that it is related to Groovy 2.5.5 in Hybris 2011. In Groovy 2.5 there were some major changes like e.g. groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance().